# Class does not have the property in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

If my JSP is :

```
<c:forEach items="${listTable1}" var="row">
    ${row['class'].getField('id') }<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

I get this:

```
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
...
public java.lang.Long org.sdbrother.model.Table1.id
```

The object of class `org.sdbrother.model.Table1` has the field `id` and `id` is a public field of the `Table1` class.

But if my JSP is:

```
<c:forEach items="${listTable1}" var="row">
    ${row.id}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.sdbrother.model.Table1' does not have the property 'id'.
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you miss the getter? getId()?

Comment: post your `Table1` class

Comment: I understood (thanks to Yggdrasil), we needed Getter and Setter. Previously worked on Mustaches templarizer